# how to add new field in a table in mysql through phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

please, I suddenly forgot how to do it. and its consuming much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html